# Email activation security checksum

Tags: php, checksum

Ive been asking around for some feedback on my website and one comment I received was the following

"I signed up with email@email.com and managed to active my account with http://www.mysite.co.uk/activateuser.php?email=email@email.com

You need checksums to stop it."

Can anybody elaborate on this and how I can implement them into my activation?

---

In theory, If I was to create a row named "rand_key" in my DB and when a user registers a random key is stored in the column, could I then use this as the activation as opposed to the email? thus making it un guessable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a unique user key, which shouldn't be related to user data. Usually you could do something like hashing the output of a random generator function in order to make it unique and use that. Then you point them to the link:

http://www.mysite.co.uk/activateuser.php?userid=generated-unique-hashed-key

This unique user key should be added as an extra field to the table where you store your user info, or related to the user in some other way. By keeping the key unrelated to user data you make sure nobody can discover a user's key and maliciously activate/do another action instead of your user.

Then you should test the user key on arrival for some conditions:

- not authorized yet - authorize
- authorized already - some error
- wrong key - some error

Also, there should be an expiration date associated with your user, upon which you just deactivate the user along with his key.

Answer (score 1):

The person means you can activate your address by going to that url and simply putting the email address in thr url.  You could do this without actually getting the activation email.

By using a checksum, you force thr user to click the link.  E.g.
Activate.php?email=aaa@bbb.com&check=A1234b23

At the time of sending the email you would geneate a random code.  Store this in your database somewhere.  Append it to the url the user is given.  When the user clicks the link, you check that the code matches the code stored for that email address.  If it matches, validate the email.  Else do not.

Comment: No need for the email in the URI at all. Just send some long, unguessable number.

Comment: If its just a numeric value, i could write a script to go from 0 to 100 million and activate all addresses then.  Email + alphanumeric code is the best way

Answer (score 1):

> In theory, If I was to create a row
>   named "rand_key" in my DB and when a
>   user registers a random key is stored
>   in the column, could I then use this
>   as the activation as opposed to the
>   email? thus making it un guessable?

Yes. Keep in mind that you don't necessarily want random as much as you want unique (in order to avoid two email addresses accidentally getting the same activation code).

You could do something like:

```
$key = mt_rand().'-'.uniqid('', true);

echo 'http://mysite.com/activate?key='.urlencode(base64_encode($key));
```

That would be tough to guess and would be guaranteed unique.